# How to run a script every hour, on the hour only on weekdays using time-based trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need to run a Google App Script script every hour on the hour only on weekdays.

It seems easy to do one of the two, but to combine it I'm not sure...

The hourly trigger:
ScriptApp.newTrigger("RefreshRates").timeBased().inTimezone("GMT").everyHours(1).nearMinute(0).create();

It needs to run every hour as close as possible to the hour.
So for example 09:00, 10:00, 11:00 etc. I know App Script not very accurate with this but then just as close as possible to the hour.

I found this that might help with the weekdays issue, but is it possible to then combine the above with something like this:

```
 function createWeeklyTrigger() {
    var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
                ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
                ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];
    for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
       ScriptApp.newTrigger("your_function_name")
                .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
                .atHour(11).create();
    }
 }
```

Ideal is actually Friday 9:45 pm till 10:15pm Sunday GMT, when Forex markets close and open...

Edit:
I think I made something not very clear in my initial question about every hour every weekday, not certain hours. But the week for markets start 22:00 Sunday GMT and ends Friday 22:00 GMT. Thus the ideal is from Sunday 22:00 GMT until Friday 22:00 GMT every hour around the hour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best choice, I think, would be setting a `Trigger` to each hour you want the script to run at, using a second loop inside the one that sets weekdays, since `everyHours()` does not accept start and end arguments.

Please, note that this will create *separate triggers* that fire on the same day of the week.

```
function setWeekdaysTrigger() {

  var startHour = 9;
  var endHour   = 13;
  var daysWeek  = []; //put Enums for days of the week here;

  //set trigger to specific week days;
  daysWeek.forEach(function(day){
    //set trigger for 9AM to 13PM;
    for(var h=startHour; h<endHour; h++) {
      var tg = ScriptApp.newTrigger('doSomething').timeBased();
          tg.onWeekDay(day);
          tg.atHour(h).nearMinute(15).create(); //arbitrary precision (minutes);
    }        
  });

}
```

As an update to the answer - please, note that, unfortunately, there are quotas on [how many triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you may create for the project on behalf of *one user* (currently equals to 20 per user per project).

### Configurable triggers

As clarified in comments, configuring *custom-days* + *custom-hours* triggers requires a more sophisticated handling. Proposed solution (not counting explicit date-time checks) is dynamic trigger configuration (since one cannot set both the `onWeekDay(day)` + `everyHours(n)` due to recurrence overlapping [I found that `onWeekDay(day)` sets implicit `everyWeeks(1)` recurrence pattern]):

First, create a main trigger function that sets days recurrence

```
function custom24trigger() {
  var days  = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY]; //put Enum values here;

  //create trigger for each date (arbitrary hours);
  days.forEach(function(day){
    for(var offset = 0; offset < 23; offset=offset+4) { //every 4 hours;
      var tg = ScriptApp.newTrigger('changeTriggers').timeBased();
          tg.onWeekDay(day).atHour(offset).create(); //change every N hours;
    }
  });

}
```

Secondly, create a trigger change function that will be fired with set recurrence, which clears previously set triggers and creates new ones:

```
function changeTriggers() {
  var triggers   = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers(); //get project's triggers;
  var props      = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); //get script properties store;
  var triggerIds = props.getProperty('triggerIds'); //get arbitrary property to set Ids to;

  //if ids are not empty, split into Array of Ids, else set up empty Array;
  if(triggerIds!==null) { triggerIds = triggerIds.split(','); }else { triggerIds = []; }

  //loop over triggers and delete saved;
  triggerIds.forEach(function(id){
    triggers.forEach(function(trigger){
      if(trigger.getUniqueId() == id) { 
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger); 
      }
    });
  });

  var today = new Date(); //current date;
  var start = today.getHours(); //current hour;

  var stop = start+3; //hour to stop (sets N triggers);

  //create hourly trigger for each hour;
  var newId = '';
  for(var h = start; h < stop; h++) {
    var trg = ScriptApp.newTrigger('doSomething').timeBased();

    //make trigger fire once at specific date and hour;
    today.setHours(h);
    today.setMinutes(0);

    var created = trg.at(today).create();   
    newId += ','+created.getUniqueId(); //get new trigger Id;
  }

  props.setProperty('triggerIds', newId); //set trigger property;
}
```

Comment: So I need a specific function to be triggered every hour on the hour on every weekday. So the weekdays will be the loop and then nested inside to run every hour?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the other way around - create the loop as usual that iterates over `Array` written to `days` variable and inside this loop the one I've suggested above - this will create triggers you need for each weekday you want, just make sure to replace weekday with something like `tg.onWeekDay(days[currentIndexOfMainLoop])`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and experiment. 
Also, I think I made something not very clear in my initial question about every hour every weekday, not certain hours.
But the week for markets start 22:00 Sunday GMT and ends Friday 22:00 GMT.
Thus the ideal is from Sunday 22:00 GMT until Friday 22:00 GMT every hour around the hour...

Comment: NP! I I see - as you need yo exclude specific days, such as Saturday, `everyDays(n)` is not an option (unless I still misunderstood you), if you want it to run 24h/day then instead of loop with at hour, use the `everyHours(1)`, only thought that there might be an hour or two when you don't need it to run

Comment: Updated the answer to account for that - btw, beware the [20 trigger per user per script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) quota!

Comment: Your latest script should ScriptApp.WeekDay.  be MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY?
Thus for each of these days a trigger is made to run every hour?
So 5 triggers in total?

Comment: @Petrus, if you need only five days then yes, add `ScriptApp.WeekDay` five times and, assuming you use the `everyHours(n)` method, only 5 will be created 
(btw, the fun extension of your question is 23-hour script that runs only 6 days in a week, if I will think of how to do that, will udate the answer just in case)

Comment: I have tested your suggestions but it does not seem to create the triggers for only the certain day(s). Rather, it creates just the amount of day(s) normal hourly triggers. Thus, the triggers are not specific for the day.

Comment: Does it then not make more sense to have a normal hourly trigger, and in the function that executes have a loop that checks if the day and time is > 22:00 Sunday GMT and < Friday 22:00 GMT?

Comment: And it seems I need to get more sleep - you are absolutely right, it disregards day of the week, I apologize... Will update the answer (as for hourly trigger with a check, then yes, ofc, it should work just as well)

Comment: thank you for your dedication! You need some triggers yourself for sleep :)

Comment: @Petrus, finally got to updating the answer - this proposal should work and is fully customizable (beware the quota, though - the more checks there are, the less the difference between `stop` and `start` should be (e.g. for 6-day checks with 2 times-a-day schedule hours left equal to 20 - (6 * 2) = 8)

Comment: Well done and think you! Seems to be working fine :)