# GoogleSheets Trigger script to run only between defined hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am familiar with setting up Triggers with GoogleSheets scripts, however, I want the script to run every 10 minutes between 9am to 5pm. Is anyone able to suggest the code I need in my function to do this?

Currently, I am only able to set a script to run every 10 minutes no matter what time of the day using the "Add Trigger" Time-Driven function, however, this runs the script every 10mins 24 hours a day.

```
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'HelloWorld!'; 
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);  
}
```

Comment: Well, setting multi-condition time-based trigger in apps script is not a very easy thing to do. Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56429286/11407695) to another question like this on SO and its discussion, this should get you started. But beware [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) as 10 mins for 8h straight can amount to a significant runtime

Comment: Or you can leave things as they are now and exit function immediately if `new Date().getHours()` is less than `9` or more than `17`, else execute desired action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change name of script to whatever you want.

```
function runFrom9to5() {
  var hour=new Date().getHours();
  if(hour>=9 && hour<17) {
    //put the rest of you script here
  }
}
```